# Most efficient small-word-size multiply for processors without a hardware multiplier

Tags: assembly, embedded, multiplication, riscv

I'm hoping to use the CH32V003 (an RV32EC processor) to do ColorChord, which makes extensive use of multiply-add's to perform DFTs. But it can operate with very low bit depths, 16- or even 8-bit multiplies.  But, the RV32EC in the CH32V003 doesn't support the RV32 multiply extension.

I've tried exploring options in godbolt, see https://godbolt.org/z/zqTEaeecr to see what the compiler would do in these situations, but it seems to only call `__mulsi3`, which performs a naive 32-bit multiply. https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/config/epiphany/mulsi3.c

What I'm hoping is that there's some ultra efficient route to do something like a combined multiply-and-shift for different situations.

Is there a good guide or discussion surrounding performing extremely efficient multiplies of special combinations of bit widths and signeness for architectures that don't have hardware multiply?

Comment: It's too bad that the hardware didn't baseline some 8-bit x 8-bit ->16-bit multiplication instructions (or even smaller) that could be used as is or to build larger multiplication widths.

Comment: There might be some hidden features in the QingKe V2A, but it's difficult to find detailed information online.

Comment: Maybe use multiplication table, e.g. 8x8 or 8x4 bits. If RAM size is enough, of course.

Comment: 2kB Ram ... 16kB flash.

Comment: @rcgldr How did you get 16 bytes? I got 4x4 bits = 16*16 = 256 bytes.

Comment: are you multiplying any two numbers or is one of them small or has a few number of bits set?

Comment: if you enable the multiply instructions does it actually do a multiply or still call the gcc lib?

Comment: @dimich - lost an edit, it would be a 256 byte table for 4x4 bits.

Comment: @old_timer - if I enable the instruction, gcc outputs it, but the processor doesn't have it.

4x4 is interesting, but unless I was specifically doing a 8x8 multiply, I believe it would be slower than the GCC technique.

Comment: Since libgcc's `__mulsi3` ends its shift-and-add loop when `a>>=1` becomes zero, it's automatically faster for small inputs, unless they're small negatives sign-extended to 32-bit.  For a small enough fixed iteration count, you might unroll without the early-out, perhaps depending on branch mispredict cost vs. pipeline depth * width.

Comment: The code as written both ensures and relies on 32 bit implicit promotion. Why would the compiler do anything else?

Comment: @CharlesLohr yes but is it making native instructions or is it still making calls to __mulsi3?

Comment: I guess as long as I manually verify the order-of-operations of each of the parameters going into the function it would be OK to use `_mulsi3` but it means I have to manually verify that "big number goes into left operand" which is a wee bit annoying.  

Side-note:  I was able to make my algorithm work much more with pow-of-2 multiples so more things turn into shifts, so it might be OK.

P.S. @old_timer If compiling with -im, it produces native instructions.

Answer (score 2):

You've got 16kB of flash available. Why don't you use 1kB for storing a "squares/4" table such as...

```
const uint16_t  Sqr_4[511]={0/4,1/4, 4/4, 9/4, 16/4, 25/4, ..., 260100/4};

uint16_t umul8b( uint8_t x, uint8_t y){

   return Sqr_4[(uint16_t)x+y]-((x>y)?Sqr_4[x-y]:Sqr_4[y-x]);
}
```

Comment: For RV32, `int` will be a 32-bit type, so `(uint16_t)x+y` will promote both sides to `int` anyway.  The cast fortunately doesn't do anything since it applies to `x` before the `+`, not tempting the compiler into wasting any instructions truncating a sum to 16-bit before it needs a 32-bit value as an offset into memory.  Portably, the sum of two `uint8_t` variables is guaranteed to not to overflow, since `int` is required to have the value-range of a 16-bit type.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks.

Comment: This is pretty wild.